# Help with bridging on a curve, and using multiple edges

Tags: mesh, edges

So currently, this is what I have
[image: Current Mesh]

My goal is to get the middle of the sides to meet in the middle, I used some photoshop to portray what I mean

[image: Goal Mesh]

Though when i do bridge, I have 2 issues

1. As you can see, there are many edges. When I go and properly select them all before the bridge, they all bridge to each other as well, so only one of them is actually accomplishing the goal.
2. When I did accidentally get it to work, each one took the shortest path possible, so rather than the curve I was looking for, I got a pavilion type look.

I am doing this one side at a time, but I just need a small bit of help with this. If bridge isn't the right tool to use, or if there is a better tool to use, please let me know. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: so you would like a topology like that? https://zupimages.net/up/20/41/92x9.jpg ... why do you need a so dense topology, or why at least don't you begin with a much lighter one?

Comment: you could create a cylinder, delete the half (x-axis) and the half (y-axis), add some loop cuts, and then use the knife (k) to cut in the hole. Then add a mirror modifier (x & y) to re-create the object.